# Changes in code not taking effect - Visual web developer

Tags: javascript, html, visual-web-developer

I have a button which is calling a function that displays an alert. The alert is displayed but if I change the messege that the alert is showing, when I press the button the alert will still show the first message I wrote and not the updated one. 
It is also happening when I add html tags, they won't show when I run the code.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you save the file and do a hard refresh?

Comment: Make sure you're saving your files and that you're testing the files you think you're testing.  You might have multiple copies and are testing an old copy.  It's impossible to say more without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You know the drill: make some edits to your document, click save, switch over to your browser, refresh it, and then observe the changes.

However, every now and again I will catch myself viewing the wrong site page, viewing the site on a different browser, or viewing the client's old live site! ***Check your address bar + go into your folder and open the page again.***